# Embed class to storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

How i can embed class to storyboard, I have designed storyboard with all the files, but now I have the class that has random image inside it and I want to show it in one of the ViewControler in storyboard???

Answer (score 1):

In your storyboard:

1. Click on your view controller
2. Click on identity inspector (third tab)
3. Type your custom class' name in 'Class' field

[image]